# Upload files with Multer without using action, method, encrypt="multipart/form-data" attributes on form tag

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

so I'm trying to upload an image with Multer but I want to use Angular's $http.post to upload the file. Not have a submit button trigger the form method and action. The problem is if I do not use encrypt, method or post attributes the req.file ends up being undefined and the image does not show up in the uploads folder.

So my question is, is there any way I can use Multer file upload not by the regular form method with action but angular's $http.post(). When I do it now the req.file is always undefined.

Here's my code for reference

app.js (Node)

```
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');
var path    = require('path');
var fs      = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var multer  = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.port || 8080;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
            cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
    });
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    res.render('index', {filename: filename });
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
    filename = req.files;
    console.log(req.files);
});

app.listen(port);
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="image">Choose Image</label>
<input id="inputImage" name="image" type="file">
<button class="form-control" ng-click="uploadFile()">Add</button>
</form>
```

So I basically want to remove this default behaviour and still get the req.file object.

And finally my Angular code:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var uploadUrl = "/upload";
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl,fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
            console.log("success!!");
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("error!!");
        });
    };
```

Please help me on this... Right now I get the $http.post() .error() callback and if I dig deep into it, it is because req.file is undefined in my node app.js

Comment: why ur using  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} ?

Comment: Should I not use this? I'm sorry but I found this snippet from another answer... So I have used it

Comment: You should send content type for images instead of undefined. Or else remove that header and try

Comment: Thanks! It is making the call but this time the upload post request came back with another error... "Unexpected token -" and other info with Body-Parser module errors... The same app.js entry point... 

And Please ignore the 'filename' variable I'm sharing with the view... In my code above I have missed declaring that variable...

Comment: Then Please upvote for my comment. For error ,If somewhere ur parsing body then use JSON.parse(JSON.string(body))

Comment: Cool... But for some funny reason I can't seem to get the upvote comment option when I hover... really sorry... This was my first question on stackoverflow... all these days other answers would do the trick... And about the body parser, could this happen because I'm sending bad JSON to my post? wondering if that is also a problem here...

Comment: Then let me add it as answer then you can accept it :P

Comment: .Sure! And I got rid of the body-parser error... I was sending invalid JSON.. But I'm yet to crack sending the file through the $http.post method... I was just checking out other questions for that... Maybe in your answer would you be kind enough how I can send the file object? 
I have the file object passed as a param to that $scope.upload() function now... But thanks a lot for help so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are using `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`
You should send content type for images instead of undefined Or else remove that header and try. 
Also by using console.log(req.body) u can check what body ur submitting