# How to save form data that include image using nodejs posted using angular 2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, angular2-forms

I am creating a application using mean stack, in which i am using angular 2 for the client side. I had created a form that contain some input fields and a image. Now, for submitting the form i am using formdata to send data to the node server. now I am unable to show, access and save the data at the node server. Please somebody help me as I am new to mean stack.

data array:

```
const newProduct = {
    category: this.pcategory,
    name: this.name,
    description: this.description,
    price: this.price,
    quantity: this.quantity,
    image: this.fileName
}
```

here is the code for sending data:
imagedata contain the data of the file

```
addProduct(newProduct, imagedata:File) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('body', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
    formData.append('file', image, newProduct.imagedata);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("enctype", "multipart/form-data"); 
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/product/add' ,formData, options).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

here is the code for receiving and saving data:

```
function (req, res) {

        var storage = multer.diskStorage({//multers disk storage settings

            destination: function (req, file, callback) {

                callback(null, './uploads');

            }

        });
        var upload = multer({//multer settings

            storage: storage

        }).any();

        var model = new Model(req.body);
        model.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.status(201).json(model);
            }
        });
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                // An error occurred when uploading
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(422).send("an Error occured")
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508558/upload-files-with-multer-without-using-action-method-encrypt-multipart-form-d

Comment: that question consists of image uploading only but i am submitting data as well. i had already complete image uploading and form submission individually but unable to complete together

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 you cannot upload image with this approach consider using this Angular 2 module [ng2-file-uploader](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload). You can see the demo app here [Angular File Uploads with an Express Backend](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-file-uploads-with-an-express-backend)
.

Comment: I do not want to use any other module. Is it is possible by any chance to do it using the basic concept of mean stack and angular 2??

Comment: Yes send Image using JS Form Data Object. Here is link how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: check out my code i am using the same but still no result. it shows blank req.body

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to convert your image to base64 string and pass that string in your model. And then have that base64 string convert back to image in the server.